# Bulk insert copy sql table with golang

Tags: sql, go

For the context, I'm new to go and I'm creating a program that can copy tables from Oracle to MySQL. 
I use `database/sql` go package, so I assume it can be used for migrating any kind of database.
To simplify my question I'm coping on the same MySQL database table name world.city to world.city_copy2.
with my following code, I ended up with the same last values in all the rows in the table :-(
do I somehow need to read through all the values inside the loop? what is the efficient way to do that?

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

const (
    user   = "user"
    pass   = "testPass"
    server = "localhost"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("test")
    conStr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s)/world", user, pass, server)
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", conStr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM city")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
    }

    columns, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
    }

    // Make a slice for the values
    values := make([]sql.RawBytes, len(columns))

    // rows.Scan wants '[]interface{}' as an argument, so we must copy the
    // references into such a slice
    scanArgs := make([]interface{}, len(values))
    for i := range values {
        scanArgs[i] = &values[i]
    }
    // that string will be generated according to len of columns
    placeHolders := "( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )"

    // slice will contain all the values at the end
    bulkValues := []interface{}{}

    valueStrings := make([]string, 0)

    for rows.Next() {
        // get RawBytes from data
        err = rows.Scan(scanArgs...)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
        }
        valueStrings = append(valueStrings, placeHolders)
        bulkValues = append(bulkValues, scanArgs...)
        //

    }
    stmStr := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO city_copy2 VALUES %s", strings.Join(valueStrings, ","))
    _, err = db.Exec(stmStr, bulkValues...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass the address of 'scanArgs' instead of itself, 
like 
err = rows.Scan(&scanArgs...)
instead of 
err = rows.Scan(scanArgs...)

Comment: still not good. 
`cannot use &scanArgs (type *[]interface {}) as type []interface {} in argument to rows.Scan`

Answer (score 2):

I have checked out the docs of the library, and it seems that the problem here is that bulkValues keeps the address of the pointer so when scanArgs changes, bulkValues also changes to latest value of that scanArgs.

You need to use the values variable to get the values like below:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Print("test")
    conStr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s)/soverflow", user, pass, server)
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", conStr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM city")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
    }

    columns, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
    }

    // Make a slice for the values
    values := make([]sql.RawBytes, len(columns))

    // rows.Scan wants '[]interface{}' as an argument, so we must copy the
    // references into such a slice
    scanArgs := make([]interface{}, len(values))
    for i := range values {
        scanArgs[i] = &values[i]
    }
    // that string will be generated according to len of columns
    placeHolders := "( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )"

    // slice will contain all the values at the end
    bulkValues := []interface{}{}

    valueStrings := make([]string, 0)
    // make an interface to keep the record's value
    record := make([]interface{}, len(columns))
    for rows.Next() {
        // get RawBytes from data
        err = rows.Scan(scanArgs...)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
        }
        valueStrings = append(valueStrings, placeHolders)
        for i, col := range values {
            // you need to be carefull with the datatypes here
            // check out the docs for details on here
            record[i] = string(value)
        }
        bulkValues = append(bulkValues, record...)
    }
    stmStr := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO city_copy2 VALUES %s", strings.Join(valueStrings, ","))
    _, err = db.Exec(stmStr, bulkValues...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

You can also find the example of the documentation [here](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/wiki/Examples).

Note: There might be more efficient ways to copy database from psql to mysql but this answer only gives a quick solution for this particular issue that you are having.

Comment: `for i, col := range values {
   // you need to be carefull with the datatypes here
   // check out the docs for details on here
   record[i] = string(col)
  }`
this is working, but will convert everything into a string, isn't it? is it possible to read it as bytes into the record list?  any idea how to make it efficient?

Comment: `strings.Repeat(",?", len(values))[1:]` is a good trick to make "?,?,?...". Same applies for constructing valueStrings without join

Comment: Isn't that Sprintf with "VALUES %s" a straight-up SQL Injection vector?